# How to set background image as header with logo and navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, eclipse

I am very new to web design and need alot of help. 
I am trying to create my very own website. The background will be the header.
On the background, the logo will be at the left, while the navigation bar will be on the right. The text will be centered at the background as well. Here is an example. Furthermore, what does position absolute means? Can anyone explain it to me? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks 
This is an example: [image]

This are my codes....

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.container {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%:
 height: 100%;
 
}

.hero {
 height: 100%:
 width: 100%;
 background-image:url(../images/Background.png);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 
}
nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;   /* remove bullet point */
 float: right;
}

nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 1em;
 padding: 0.5em; 
}

nav a {
 font-weight: 800;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul a:hover {
 color: #f13647;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in;        
 padding: 15px 0;     
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Josh</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.40753.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Test.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="hero">
    <img src="images/logoo.png" alt="Logo FitnessX " class="logo">
    <nav class="sitenavigation">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="Work.html"></a>Work</li>
      <li><a href=""></a>Blog</li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="home-hero">
     <h2>Hello my name is josh</h2>
     <p>I am 18 years old</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).
However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

Note: A "positioned" element is one whose position is anything except static.

Here is a simple example:

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
} 

div.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<h2>position: absolute;</h2>

<p>An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed):</p>
<div class="absolute">This div element has position: absolute; (ancestor is body) </div>
<div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;
  <div class="absolute">This div element has position: absolute;</div>
</div>
<div class="relative">This div also has positio: relative; which positions the div after the top div</div>
```

for more information see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and try some examples

Comment: **An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position.** I dont see what you mean

Answer (score 0):

at hero class change your height with pixel:

```
.hero {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give one common `div` for the containers you want to have background applied to like :

```html
<div class='bg-img'>
   <nav>Your navbar</nav>
   <header>Your header</header>
</div>
```

and in CSS apply `bg` to your `.bg-img` container :

```css
.bg-img {
  background-img: url('someimg');
}
```